# How to make app compatible running Ice Cream Sandwich devices

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've app built on Androi-2.3.3 (gingerbread). When I run this app on 4.0.3 (Ice cream sandwich), I see issue with webviews. I've two questions:

1. How can I fix the functionality to run on 4.0.3. Is there anyway to fix it inline in codebase? I mean when a ICS device runs it, it should pick the correct version of code.
2. Are there any known issues with webviews devices running 4.0.3?

Answer (score 4):

To check version

```
int sdk_version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

So you could set your function to base on android version by:

```
int sdk_version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; 
if (sdk_version < 11) // less than 3.0
{
// your func for less 2.3.3
}
else
{
// your func for 3.0 or more
}
```